# How disable button until the next day after on click

Tags: javascript, button, disable

I am completely lost, I have a website where the user can login, after login I would like to add a button which deactivates after a click and reactivates the next day (every midnight), I would like the button to remain deactivated even if the user disconnects and reconnects or if they try from smartphone.

Please help

Comment: If the button has to stay disabled even if the user try to access from a different device, then you need to store the button status on server-side. It can be done in a number of different ways; for example you can have a simple text file that is automatically deleted every day at midnight, you can save the information in a database.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems I'm not good enough to do something as much complicated

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here essentially.

If you're using a back end system for user login, I would recommend disabling user login that way. Using this method you typically wouldn't go as far as to disable the login button, but instead lock the account and deny entry if the correct credentials are entered.

<strike>If you're not using any sort of back end system, your only option really is using cookies. These definitely are **not** a secure method of preventing login as they are easily manipulated by the user. Mozilla has a page explaining cookies [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) much better than I ever could. These cookies are method of persistent storage. You can create a cookie that will expire at midnight, and use javascript to search for that cookie when the page loads. If the cookie exists, just go ahead and disable the button.</strike>

All that being said, disabling login on the back end is the far more secure way to go. I would not recommend using cookies for something like login prevention in most cases.

Edit: removed section suggesting cookies as a poor alternative. Missed the section stating they needed it across devices.

Comment: "*I would like the button to remain deactivated even if the user disconnects and reconnects **or if they try from smartphone**.*" How would a cookie set on desktop prevent the user from clicking on the same button from his mobile phone?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm not comfortable with the idea of using cookie and I cannot deny entry to the account because my user can access to different service from their account.

Comment: I missed the note of cross-device blocking. I'm afraid your only option then is to store the button state server side. I would also still argue that quite literally just disabling the button isn't the most secure approach either, as the user *could* just call the login function themselves from the console. You could keep a list of services that the account is not allowed to use and check that list when the client is trying to access a service.